# Is there a source for this Segulah to help somebody become pregnant?

Tags: sources-mekorot, pregnancy-birth, segulah

There seems to be a Segulah to help a woman who is having trouble having a child.

The Segulah is to form a group of 40 women (or more) who will say Tefilas Chana (Perek Aleph and Perek Bais in the Navi Shmuel Aleph) at the same time, specifically 10 minutes after Licht Bentching, for 40 consecutive times.

Comment: Where did you hear of it from? Perhaps that is the source?

Comment: Haven't heard of it.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Elchonon and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Sounds like a made up thing.

Comment: As has been said here many times, "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.”
With that in mind, I have checked the following sites for segulos for having children:
קרוב ל-30 סגולות לזכות בזרע של קיימא - מוסדות שומע תפילה בכותל המערבי (tfilot.org)  - approx 30 segulos;
http://www.kaduri.net/?CategoryID=497&ArticleID=1857 – 9  segulos;
https://www.hidabroot.org/article/213567 – 16 segulos from Rav Chaim Kanievski
סגולות לזרע של קיימא - הידברות (hidabroot.org)  – 5 segulos

and the suggested seguloh is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I found a close iteration of this segula here

"Segulos for Zera Kayama – Better Than a Segulah" https://www.betterthanasegulah.org/free-services/segulos/segulos-for-zera-kayama/

Number 23:

If a woman is having difficulty with child raising or she doesn’t have children altogether, it is a segulah to say the haftorah of the first day of Rosh Hashanah (“Vayehi ish echad min haRamasayim Tzofim…”) after hadlakas neiros. She should understand the words that she is saying and say it with kavannah, and she should give tzeddakah before lighting the candles. Through this she will be remembered for children who are talmidei chachamim and tzaddikim. (In Yerushalayim this is an established custom in the name of the Arizal.)

Although it doesn't mention having 40 women say it at the same time,  it's pretty close.

(The Haftara for the 1st day Rosh Hashanah includes tefilas Chana)